# Splitting single-columned .CSV into multiple columns with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm interested to know how to elegantly go about splitting a single-columned file of the following format into a more classic tabular layout using Pandas.

(The file is received as an output from an eye tracker.)

**Current Format:**

```
TimeStampGazePointXLeftGazePointYLeftGazePointXRightGazePointYRight
00000000.11111111111111.22222222222222.33333333333333.4444444444444
00000000.11111111111111.22222222222222.33333333333333.4444444444444
00000000.11111111111111.22222222222222.33333333333333.4444444444444
```

**Desired Format:**

```
TimeStamp GazePointXLeft GazePointYLeft GazePointXRight GazePointYRight
000000000 11111111111111 22222222222222 333333333333333 444444444444444
000000000 11111111111111 22222222222222 333333333333333 444444444444444
000000000 11111111111111 22222222222222 333333333333333 444444444444444
```

**Where I'm stuck:**
I imagine the solution will involve Pandas' `split` method but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get there. I imagine I'll have to "manually" add the respective columns while somehow splitting period-delimited rows of data...

```
df = pd.DataFrame('data.csv')

headers = ["TimeStamp", ...,  "GazePointYRight"]

for header in headers:
    df[header] = df[1:].split(".")[headers.index(header)] <--- # Splitting rows by period and taking data based on header index in list
```

I'd really appreciate some direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas.read_...` has several usefull parameters to play with.

I believe you want something like this?

```py
import pandas as pd

columns_names = [
    'TimeStamp',
    'GazePointXLeft',
    'GazePointYLeft',
    'GazePointXRight',
    'GazePointYRight',
    ]

df = pd.read_csv("lixo.csv", sep='.', skiprows=1, names=columns_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to fix upon reading the csv:

```
headers = ["TimeStamp", ...,  "GazePointYRight"]
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='.', skiprows=1, names=headers)
```

Its is also possible to do afterwards:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
headers = ["TimeStamp", ...,  "GazePointYRight"]
df = df.TimeStampGazePointXLeftGazePointYLeftGazePointXRightGazePointYRight.str.split('.', expand=True)
df.rename(columns={n:name for n, name in enumerate(headers)}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Seems like fixing it upon read is the way to go. Thanks! I don't have much reputation so my +1 may not appear, but I appreciate it.